# Problem with geting wifiInfo while app is in background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am geting `wifiInfo` like that:

```
val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
Log.d("###", wifiInfo.ssid.toString())
```

But when app is in background `wifiInfo` always return `<unknown ssid>`.
How can i get it?

EDIT:

In `MainActivity` I starting coroutine that prints connected wifi SSID every second:

```
job = MainScope().launch {
    while(true) {
        val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
        Log.d("###", "SSID: ${wifiInfo.ssid.toString()}")
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

Screenshot from **Logcat**:
[image]

Can see, that SSID stops printing properly after any seconds in background.

Comment: From the docs. Guide to background work : https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Comment: @Amal , they recommends to use `Coroutines` or `WorkManager` to run background processes, i tried both of them, but it does not solve my problem because I can not get exactly `wifiInfo` in background and not start the background process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlexVs86 I tried your provided code.

Solution:
After **API 29** `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions is not enough in manifest, you have to add `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` for background location access.

Here, I tried permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

OutPut: After granting permission to **Allow all the time** it provides the information in background as well.

```
D/###: SSID: <unknown ssid>
D/###: SSID: <unknown ssid>
D/###: SSID: <unknown ssid>
D/###: SSID: <unknown ssid>
D/###: SSID: <unknown ssid>
D/###: SSID: <unknown ssid>
D/###: SSID: <unknown ssid>
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
D/###: SSID: "Home1_EXT"
```